# Not able to instatiate Repository bean in Springboot test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-test

I try to test my JPA in Springboot but I get error as following. Referred several threads related to it and tried every solution but none of them are working.

If I use @MockBean for repository class, the data is not persisting and retrieving. IF I use @Autowired, I am getting the above error.

I used @SpringbootTest as well as @DataJpaTest with @ContextConfiguration but none of the annotations solves the problem. What am I missing here? Please help.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.api.repository.StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository]: Specified class is an interface

```
import de.api.entity.StyledLayerDescriptorEntity;
import de.api.entity.StyledLayerDescriptorEntityBuilder;
import de.api.repository.StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository;
import de.api.service.StyledLayerDescriptorStorageService;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Optional;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {de.api.repository.StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository.class})
@DataJpaTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository styledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository;

    @Test
    @Profile(("Test"))
    public void testRepository(){
        String sldId = "5c0405b0-2a09-4d52-a702-6395445bd575";
        StyledLayerDescriptorEntity sld =
                new StyledLayerDescriptorEntityBuilder(
                        sldId,
                        OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-03-11T09:00:07Z"),
                        "my content")
                        .build();
        styledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository.save(sld);
        Optional<StyledLayerDescriptorEntity> sldRes = styledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository.findById(sldId);

    }
}
```

Repository class

```
package de.api.repository;

import de.api.entity.StyledLayerDescriptorEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@Repository
public interface StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository extends JpaRepository<StyledLayerDescriptorEntity, String> {

    public final static String FIND_BY_TIME_STAMP = "SELECT S.id FROM StyledLayerDescriptorEntity S WHERE S.timestamp<:timestamp";
    @Query(FIND_BY_TIME_STAMP)
    public List<String> findByTimeStamp(@Param("timestamp")OffsetDateTime timestamp);
}
```

Entity class

```
package de.api.entity;
    
import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "StyledLayerDescriptor")
public class StyledLayerDescriptorEntity {
  @Id private String id;

  private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(max)")
  private String sldContent;

  public StyledLayerDescriptorEntity() {}

  public StyledLayerDescriptorEntity(String id, OffsetDateTime timestamp, String sldContent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.sldContent = sldContent;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getSldContent() {
    return sldContent;
  }

  public void setSldContent(String sldContent) {
    this.sldContent = sldContent;
  }

  public OffsetDateTime getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }

  public void setTimestamp(OffsetDateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }

}
```

Entity Builder

```
package de.api.entity;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class StyledLayerDescriptorEntityBuilder {

  private String id;
  private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
  private String sldContent;

  public StyledLayerDescriptorEntityBuilder(String id, OffsetDateTime timestamp, String sldContent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.sldContent = sldContent;
  }

    public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public OffsetDateTime getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }

  public void setTimestamp(OffsetDateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }

  public String getSldContent() {
    return sldContent;
  }

  public void setSldContent(String sldContent) {
    this.sldContent = sldContent;
  }

  public StyledLayerDescriptorEntity build() {
    return new StyledLayerDescriptorEntity(id, timestamp, sldContent);
  }
}
```

Comment: `de.api.repository.StyledLayerDescriptorStorageRepository` is not a `@Configuration` class, why would you put it in `@ContextConfiguration.classes`? Have you tried running your test with `@DataJpaTest` only?

Comment: Yes. I tried both with SpringBootTest and DataJpaTest seperately to test the persistance layer. I don't get errors when I use MockBean. But it is not doing any data transaction Operation in Test class.

Comment: Does the error persist if you change `@ContextConfiguration.classes` to your Spring Boot application, or remove it completely?

Comment: Try to remove `@Component` and `@Repository` from your repository class

Comment: I tried it. I am not getting expected result. Testing of Persistence layer is not functioning when I use MockBean. My head is breaking.